# Split of XML files

Tags: c, xml

I am working on xml file but unfortunately my xml file is become large. So now I want to split my xml file into multiple smaller xml files. Is it possible to split one large xml file into multiple smaller xml files.

For E.g.  If we make any project in c language then we create multiple c files but the main function will always be present in one c file. All other functions or sub programs we keep in different c files. So if we have to call any function we call it from the c file which is having main function.

Same or similar to that I want in my xml file where there will be one main xml file and all other xml file would be dependent on the main xml file.

In simple words I want to split my large xml file into smaller xml files. I don't have any idea about it. I request you all that please share an example or link for any example of this kind of thing.
Thanks

Comment: There is no generic answer to this. It depends on your xml file and the application that uses it.

Comment: There is no way where I can split large xml file into smaller one

Comment: XML is not a programming language. It's just a text file of data. If you want a smaller one, that means either you have a (new) way to break the data file into multiple smaller text (XML) file to process, or... why you care its very large (1GB? 10GB?) if you're not doing a DOM but a SAX parsing and run through the data processing without fear.

Comment: Perhaps you could use XML Inclusions ([Xinclude](https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/)) if your XML parser supports it.

Comment: Can you explain why you think the file is 'too large', and exactly how large is it?   A 1MB file is large for an embedded system, but it's tiny for most PCs.

Comment: @neil I am implementing xml file in [klish](http://libcode.org/projects/klish/). So we are implementing some commands for a equipment for that we are using klish. Now the problem is in one xml file I have made many commands so it is now becoming very difficult to track all commands in one xml file. So we decided to split that xml file into multiple xml file so that it become easy to track all command.

Comment: Large xml files should be read using an XmlReader, not split

Comment: @Ian Abbott  Thank you. Your suggestion helped me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to split the file into smaller parts you can use the `split` command in terminal.

```
Usage: split [OPTION] [INPUT [PREFIX]]
Output fixed-size pieces of INPUT to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...; default
size is 1000 lines, and default PREFIX is `x'.  With no INPUT, or when INPUT
is -, read standard input.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
-a, --suffix-length=N   use suffixes of length N (default 2)
-b, --bytes=SIZE        put SIZE bytes per output file
-C, --line-bytes=SIZE   put at most SIZE bytes of lines per output file
-d, --numeric-suffixes  use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic
-l, --lines=NUMBER      put NUMBER lines per output file
    --verbose           print a diagnostic to standard error just
                        before each output file is opened
    --help     display this help and exit
    --version  output version information and exit
```